# cant run project unless add code to R.java

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

I am getting an error with my code, I cannot run my project unless I add code to my R.Java but I cannot add code to the R.Java, it automatically reverts it to the generated version.

VewTask.java

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ViewTask extends Activity {
    protected TaskerDbHelper db;
    List<Task> list;
    MyAdapter adapt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_task);
        db = new TaskerDbHelper(this);
        list = db.getAllTasks();
        adapt = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.list_inner_view, list);
        ListView listTask = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listTask.setAdapter(adapt);
    }

    public void addTaskNow(View v) {
        EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String s = t.getText().toString();
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "enter the task description first!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        } else {
            Task task = new Task(s, 0);
            db.addTask(task);
            Log.d("tasker", "data added");
            t.setText("");
            adapt.add(task);
            adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_view_task, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {

        Context context;
        List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<Task>();
        int layoutResourceId;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                List<Task> objects) {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, objects);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.taskList = objects;
            this.context = context;
        }

        /**
         * This method will DEFINe what the view inside the list view will
         * finally look like Here we are going to code that the checkbox state
         * is the status of task and check box text is the task name
         */
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            CheckBox chk = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_inner_view,
                        parent, false);
                chk = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkStatus);
                convertView.setTag(chk);

                chk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                        Task changeTask = (Task) cb.getTag();
                        changeTask.setStatus(cb.isChecked() == true ? 1 : 0);
                        db.updateTask(changeTask);
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() + " is "
                                        + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }

                });
            } else {
                chk = (CheckBox) convertView.getTag();
            }
            Task current = taskList.get(position);
            chk.setText(current.getTaskName());
            chk.setChecked(current.getStatus() == 1 ? true : false);
            chk.setTag(current);
            Log.d("listener", String.valueOf(current.getId()));
            return convertView;
        }

    }

}
```

My error is in the onCreateOptionsMenu():

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_view_task, menu);
```

and in getView()

```
chk = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkStatus);
```

activity_view_task.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ViewTask" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>


    <Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
       android:text="@string/button"
       android:onClick="addTaskNow"/>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my other xml file that includes the checkbox list_inner_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <CheckBox
       android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:focusable="false"
       android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
       android:text="CheckBox" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The specific error messages say for the menu and chkStatus : "menu cannot be resolved or is not a field" and "chkStatus cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: Where is activity_view_task.xml?

Comment: Also, what, exactly, is the error you're getting?  Post LogCat.

Comment: @John Updated with errors and xml file

Comment: @user12074577 what version of java compiler do you use?

Comment: im using the android ADT that comes with the SDK from googles site

Comment: @user12074577 no, I mean the Java Compiler. You can check at Window>preference>Java>Compiler. For Example mine is 1.6, HBU?

Comment: @user12074577 I assume your project does not have any problem. I usually try to use 1.6 and have no problem with the R.java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Project->Clean...->Clean your project. `R.java` should get recreated and should hopefully solve your issues.

Comment: @user12074577 First, do you have a file in res/menu/ called `activity_view_task.xml`? Second, You never declared a `<CheckBox>` in your xml, yet you are trying to find it with `findViewById`, this will return a null pointer since it does not exist.

Comment: ah! I fixed the first error, now I have the error with the chkStatus, the R.id.chkStatus

Comment: I think everything that you have declared in you `getView` should actually go into your `onCreate`. Try that and let me know how that works.

Comment: can you show me what you mean? Because I got a ton of other errors from trying what I thought you meant haha. All I did to fix the other error was change from r.menu to r.layout because my xml file is in my layout folder. I think it just cannot find chkStatus

Comment: I think I got ahead of myself... first, where do you declare `<CheckBox android:id="@+id/chkStatus" ... />` in your xml's?

Comment: haha that's what I was missing, I didnt declare it, I called it android:id="@+id/checkBox1"